# coping mongo collection fails to maintain insertion order

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

The following command needs to copy a previously "dumped" mongo database from local machine to Mongodb cluster "Atlas", which it does but it fails to maintain the order of documents.

```js
mongorestore --maintainInsertionOrder --ssl --db=myDB --host cluster0-shard-00-00-oko1k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-oko1k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-oko1k.mongodb.net:27017 --authenticationDatabase admin --dir=dump/myDB -u myname --password mypassowrd --drop
```

Any idea what is the fix so that the order of the collection at the destination is maintained?

Comment: Order is not guaranteed but I'm sure your collection will have some kind of sort key, so you can query documents back in order you desired.

Comment: Do you need to supply a value with the flag i.e. something like `--maintainInsertionOrder true`?